# How do I unlock more bonus worlds in Metal Slug Defense?

Tags: ios, metal-slugs-defense

In Metal Slug Defense for iPhone and Android the game sporadically tells you about a bonus world which will be playable for around 5 to 60 minutes.

After freeing every Prisoner of War (POW) in each level of one bonus world the world becomes permanent playable and will not disappear anymore.

My problem is that I am not getting new messages about the next bonus worlds (or: no new bonues worlds become playable). Is there any requirement I have to meet? I already finished World 2 (hard mode) but do not have all POWs freed by now.

Any ideas?

Comment: wow, some hours after writing this question I encountered the 2nd bonus world for the first time? I am not sure how this could happen. There was an update lately (I guess it has been on saturday), maybe this was the problem for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bonus stage start everyday at (random) 10:00AM, 4:00PM or 6:00PM for 60min.

You can see all bonus stage throught the POW screen (3 on the first world, for normal and Hard).

You cannot see Bonus stage 2 before clearing Bonus stage 1, and Bonus stage 3 need Bonus stage 2 to be cleared.

On the second world (unlocked after clearing the hard mode of the first world), there is one bonus stage by day, all day.

Comment: Thank you. In fact I finally noticed it myself (I have already freed all POW). I guess I had been playing always at the wrong time lol!